# Yii2 file download using custom components

Tags: download, controller, routes, yii2, components

In yii2 project I am using components in order to download a file whose path is saved in my database.

I have setup the download button in my action column

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template'=>'{update}{pdf}{delete}',
                'buttons'=>[
                    // to display pdf icon.
                   'pdf' => function ($url, $model) {    
                                $id = [];
                                foreach ($model->sdsrefs as $mod)
                                    $id[] = $mod->file_id;
                                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>', Url::to(['product/download', 'id' => implode($id)]), [

                                   ]);                      
                            }
                ],
                'options'=>[
                    'style'=>'width:70px;'
                ]
  ],
```

I have setup the link to the controller action in the above code.

My controller action

```
public function actionDownload($id)
    {
        Yii::$app->files->downloadFile($id);
        $searchModel = new ProductSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);

    }
```

In the controller action I am calling the component in order to download. What happens here is instead of downloading when i click the PDF button it echoes out the content in the page. When I press the Pdf button I want it perform dowload of the file.

my download function in the component.

```
 public static function downloadFile($id) {
        $file = File::findOne($id);
        $filepath = Files::getFilePath($id);
        if (file_exists($filepath)) {
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file->file_name);
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
            readfile("$filepath");
        }else{
            echo "file not exist: ".$filepath;            
        }
        exit;
    }
```

How can I achieve my result .i.e download when I click on the pdf action button?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use sendFile() method of Response object?

```
return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($pathFile, $filename);
```

Check documentation at: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#sendFile()-detail

Comment: The file path has already been implemented in our project. So we need to use the set up filepaths and download options using the components